# Uninsured motor vehicle drivers in the USA - why is the liability insurance requirement not enforced better?

Tags: united-states, policy, regulation, transportation, insurance

In the USA, like in many other countries, liability insurance is mandatory for motor vehicles in almost every state. However, a significant number of drivers drive without insurance:

> Despite laws that compel the purchase of auto insurance, many people
> choose to drive without it. According to the Insurance Research
> Council (IRC), 12.6% of motorists, or about one in eight drivers, were
> uninsured in 2019. Uninsured motorist rates can vary widely by state,
> from 3.1% in New Jersey to 29.4% in Mississippi.

[NAIC -  Uninsured Motorists](https://content.naic.org/cipr-topics/uninsured-motorists)

For a legal requirement, noncompliance rates of 12-29% seems very high - and it seems to be a real problem, as many people get into accidents with uninsured drivers and are saddled with the cost.

With that background, the question:
**Why is the insurance requirement not enforced better?**

---

As a contrast, in Germany liability vehicle insurance is also mandatory, and the rate of uninsured drivers is about 0.01% ([Nirgends fahren weniger unversicherte Autos als in Deutschland](https://www.automobilwoche.de/agenturmeldungen/nirgends-fahren-weniger-unversicherte-autos-als-deutschland)); in France it's about 1.5% ([Bientôt un fichier des véhicules non assurés à disposition des policiers](https://www.europe1.fr/societe/bientot-un-fichier-des-vehicules-non-assures-a-disposition-des-policiers-3720548)).

In Germany, the insurance requirement is enforced by requiring proof of insurance during vehicle registration (i.e. no number plate without insurance). Additionally, if the insurance contract is terminated or lapses due to non-payment, the insurance company must report this to the registration authority, which can take enforcement action.

In France, similarly, the police has a database of all insured vehicles, which lets them quickly decide whether a vehicle is properly insured.

Why is there no similar system in the USA? It seems that better enforcement is possible, so there must be a political reason why it is not happening.

Comment: Its interesting that you picked Germany as an example. Ask the average German if they'd consider driving on a suspended license and the most common response would be that of confusion as if you're speaking a totally foreign concept. No drivers license, no driving. In the US, driving without, on a suspended, or revoked license is common enough that you can get a story about it in every bar you visit. I'm not sure that this question is answerable in a direct sense. Your sub-question "Why is there no similar system in the USA?" is answerable in relation to jurisdiction boundaries.

Comment: As far as I know, Illinois requires proof of insurance at license plate sticker renewal.

Comment: @DavidS That also seems to be predominantly an enforcement issue. If you are stopped by police and driving without a valid licence in Germany there will be severe fines and being caught is sufficiently likely so this is extremely rare in practice. It seems in the US either the fines are not nearly as bad or the chance to be caught is much lower, either way it also an enforcement issue.

Comment: @quarague, I would argue that drivers without a license are not all that likely to be caught in Germany, yet if they are caught there is a severe punishment. This may deter some, while others gamble on the low likelihood of getting caught. Driving without insurance is completely different, because that sticker is outside the car, not inside the motorist's wallet.

Comment: On the page linked it notes that "82% of uninsured drivers indicated they can't afford insurance or that their vehicle is inoperable or not in use," which are two completely different situations both legally and in the context of risk to other people.  It makes me wonder whether the site is equating "uninsured car" with "uninsured motorist," which wouldn't be surprising since it seems to be run by insurance commissioners who are effectively a special interest on behalf of insurers.

Comment: Just for comparison, it is estimated around 4% of drivers in the UK are uninsured.

Comment: In Germany, it's very difficult to own an uninsured car except by stealing it.

Comment: The % here in Oklahoma is apparently 25%, and we have the exact same requirements you mention. I have to present proof of insurance when I renew my car registration **every year**, and if you don't renew its obvious to passing cops from the expired stickers on your license plate. (and you do **not** want to give US cops an excuse to pull you over). So perhaps the issue *isn't* "enforcement" like the question assumes?

Comment: @JackAidley Don't we enforce insurance automatically with ANPR and database lookups? Granted that's the car not the specific driver, but 4% seems a bit high.

Comment: @Rup: we do, but there's still a surprisingly large number of uninsured drivers.

Comment: @o.m. without a license and insurance it's impossible to legally own a car in Germany, at least not a road legal. one, and you'd have no license plates. Same in the Netherlands. A car without plates would draw a lot of police attention, a car with stolen plates would get hit at the next ANPR site, of which there are plenty.

Comment: @Rup a lot of those 4% are lapsed insurance policies, and those get picked up and get fined. Most then either pay the insurance and get their car back or figure out it's not worth the money (mostly old clunkers) and the cars get destroyed.

Comment: @jwenting, DavidS wrote about the *driver's licence*, not the vehicle registration, I believe, and I replied to that. *Fahren ohne Fahrerlaubnis* is a lot more common than the criminal records show. That's in contrast to driving an unregistered vehicle, which is indeed difficult.

Comment: @o.m. without a license you can't get a car registered...

Comment: @jwenting, that's news to me, and quick googling got me [this](https://www.allianzdirect.de/kfz-versicherung/fahrzeughalter-ratgeber/). As a *Fahrzeughalter* without *Führerschein* I'm responsible for it being insured, and for not letting unlicensed drivers (or myself) drive.

Comment: How does enforcement compare to other driving offences, such as drink driving, speeding, driving without lights, etc? I get the sense that the US doesn't bother that much about these things, hence its very high death rate.

Answer (score 17):

So first, as your statistics state, 29.4% is the rate in the state of Mississippi and 3% is the rate in New Jersey.  The other 48 states, DC, and the 5 inhabited territories fall somewhere within that range.  Driving laws in the U.S. are set by the states individually so there isn't going to be a database of insured cars available on a national scale because the national government doesn't get involved in traffic law enforcement.   Most insured statuses are thus provided by a proof of insurance documents by the driver on traffic stops.  And it does get enforced, however, the cops won't know if you're violating it until they stop you for a valid reason.  And cops can't just stop you to check if you have insurance or a valid license.

As for the disparity between the two states listed, that's a matter of where those states are.  New Jersey is a small state with the highest population density of any state in the union.   The northern half is practically a suburb of New York City and the Southern Half is a Philadelphia suburb, both cities famous for, among other things, not being in New Jersey... and cops love to give tickets to out of state drivers (they tend to just pay the ticket because going to court in another state to fight it isn't worth it... so, since most of the residents are commuting out of state, they aren't going to give cops another reason).  But on top of that, New Jersey benefits from the many mass transit options that come with being suburban NYC... so if they aren't insured or have a suspended license, they don't need to worry too much about driving anyway.

Mississippi on the other hand is a very rural state... despite its larger size than New Jersey, the population density is way less.  And one of the things I've notice when Europeans ask about why Americans do certain things... is that they fail to realize that America is so damn huge.  To give you an idea of how big the U.S. if you took the First Transcontinental Railroad and placed it's western terminus (Oakland, CA) in Portugal and ran the line east from there, the eastern terminus (Council Bluffs Iowa) would be somewhere in Asiatic Russia.  And Iowa is famous for, among other things, being about halfway between the west coast and the east coast in terms of the country.  And Americans like that space because it means we can live in places where no one can reasonably bother us without having to commit to doing it.   So... losing the right to legally drive in Mississippi is way more devastating than if you lost it in New Jersey.  There is no reliable mass transit in Mississippi because there are not enough masses to transit...  If you need to go take care of some business in town, the car is the only way to do it (I lived on the east coast in one of the most heavily populated parts of the country... and I had to drive for 10 minutes to get to the nearest "convenience store" from the house I grew up in.  The interior is way worse).  So if you didn't pay your insurance or you got your license suspended, and you have to go into town... so long as the cops don't catch you, there's nothing to stop you from driving there.

To go on what @David S. said, the German who has no insurance or drive on a suspended license says it is impossible to drive a car because driving a car without those things is illegal.   The American who has no insurance or driver's license will say it's possible to drive a car because "the engine works, doesn't it?"

All of this discounts that sometimes people make honest mistakes (I got busted for driving on a suspended license, but the reason my license was suspended was because of an unpaid ticket from a few months prior.  But the cop could see that it was marked as paid.  What had happened was somewhere in the bureaucracy, the people who got the money for the ticket failed to inform the DMV that I paid the ticket (and I paid it close to the deadline) so they never removed me from the list of people who should not have their licenses suspended for unpaid tickets...  So I had no idea (stuff like this happens way more with insurance as it's easier to miss a payment and notification of a lack of payment).

Comment: If you placed Oakland CA in Lisbon, Council Bluffs Iowa would be in Prague and not in Russia in any form.

Comment: _America is so damn huge_ - Europe is slightly bigger than USA (as well as Canada). https://www.quora.com/Why-are-pickups-not-a-thing-in-Europe-nearly-as-much-as-they-are-in-the-U-S-My-U-S-contacts-say-they-indeed-use-these-pickups-to-move-stuff-too-bulky-for-a-car-trunk-what-sort-of-stuff-and-why-dont-we-have-this-need/answer/Thorstein-Klingenberg?comment_id=217377205&comment_type=2

Comment: #TIL that New Jersey is the _fourth smallest_ US state — it ranks #47 on [Wikipedia's List of US states & etc by area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_area). ...Huh. Always Seemed bigger! (And I'm saying that as a NYC native since birth; if _anyone_ was gonna unfairly minimize New Jersey, it'd be me.)

Comment: (If you go by _land_ area NJ becomes fifth-smallest. Because apparently, the size of Hawai'i really, _reeeeeally_ depends on whether you're including all the wet parts. It's either #43 (total area) or #47 (land area).)

Comment: "they never removed me from the list of people who should not have their licenses suspended for unpaid tickets" - I think there is more negation in this sentence than what was intended.

Comment: @Taemyr It doesn't not lack non-unintuitive negatives, ain't that not the truth?

Comment: @ToddWilcox If that's the case, you should definitely put it as an answer (with sources), because that is unexpected to most non-Americans.

Comment: One other factor may be that the site in the OP may be conflating uninsured vehicles with uninsured motorists.  In states with large rural areas, especially farmland, you probably have a lot of vehicles that are only driven on private property and aren't required to be insured nor pose a risk to motorists on public roads.

Comment: Driving without insurance in Germany is very difficult. You can't buy a car without a letter from an insurance company that the car is insured (for fourteen days). If you don't buy insurance within these fourteen days, that insurance company will inform the police. If you stop paying for the insurance, the insurance company will tell you and the police at the same time that your insurance has run out, and police _will_ come to your home and make sure you can't drive that car.

Comment: @alamar Vienna, Austria is a better fit.  (The great circle from Oakland to Council Bluffs is 1430 freedom units, while Lisbon to Prague is "only" 1387 FUs.  Lisbon to Vienna is 1435 FUs.)

Comment: @d-b but half of it is in Russia.

Comment: @d-b With more than twice the population.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: "many states do not require liability insurance". According to [this Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/car-insurance/liability-insurance/), only New Hampshire, Virginia and South Carolina do not require liability insurance - and Virginia introduced this in 2023 (bill SB 951), so it's down to two states.

Comment: @sleske Yeah I think this has changed over the years. It’s been a while since I paid attention to that.

Comment: @RonJohn "But?"

Comment: @d-b but how many Europeans actually think of northern Russia when they say "Europe"?  Kinda like how Alaska and Hawaii aren't considered when people talk about how huge the US is.

Comment: @RonJohn:  Russians, at the very least, do not consider themselves "Westerners" a term that is generally used in this context to describe Europe and the Americas.

Answer (score 3):

When I was living in Belgium I learned that the majority of enforcement comes from communication between DMV and insurance companies. That database is then linked with ALPR cameras, both stationary and on police vehicles. Your plate is run all the time to see if you're in compliance.

ALPRs in the USA however are not that common (sadly they are popping up more and more [1]). So the searches need to be done manually. Which takes time. And even then the insurance information might not be there.

Something that I have seen many times in Belgium is basically pulling everybody over who takes an exit off of the freeway, just out of sight so you don't know,  and they basically check everybody's driver license, registration and insurance. Something that is absolutely illegal in most states, as you cannot pull over people without reason. [2]

Lastly, and this is more anecdotal, but in many states you don't have to wait to get plates when you buy a new car. California for example gives you a paper 'plate' and will mail you a real one. All because you can walk into a dealership, and get that instant satisfaction of driving a depreciating asset off of the lot, versus Belgium, where you wouldn't be allowed to pick up your car without the plates nor proof of insurance.
In California insurance is even required to cover your new car at the same rates as your old one for 3 days. Just so that you can buy your car on a Sunday!

[1] https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/insurance/how-police-catch-uninsured-drivers

[2] https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-officer-pull-over-reason.html

Comment: Had to react to the "absolutely illegal" - An O.V.I. checkpoint is a legal stop the government can make if you're driving. Basically, the United States Supreme Court, along with the Ohio Supreme Court, has made it lawful for the police officers to set up a checkpoint and stop random amounts of cars to determine whether or not they are drinking. At the checkpoint you will be asked to provide your driver's license, proof of insurance and vehicle registration. You may be asked a brief list of screening questions such as where you are coming from and how much you have had to drink.